# systemd After [unit] option not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, init

I have the following `myweb.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=myweb - A simple hello world program
After=bluetooth.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p 2222:4343 manikanth/webapp
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I purposefully disabled `bluetooth.service` and checked. But still the service becomes active. I thought it could be due to `WantedBy` and hence I commented it. The problem persists still

What's the right way not to **bring up** the service if the dependent service e.g. `bluetooth.service` is not active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `Requisite=` option along with the `After=` option.

From the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requisite=)

> Similar to Requires=. However, if the units listed here are not started already, they will not be started and the transaction will fail immediately.

`Requires=` does not work in this case is because the `bluetooth.service` will be started when you start `myweb.service`. `Requisite=` option will not attempt to start the `bluetooth.service`. However, it will show the `myweb.service` as failed.

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked it. But you nailed it. _/\\_

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, You are looking to activate `myweb.service` only if `bluetooth.service` is up otherwise don't trigger `myweb.serbice`. If that's correct then read the below answer otherwise please do correct me!

You should really use `Requires` along with `After`.
Using `After` just configures the ordering dependencies between the unit files but `Requires` will ensure if the dependency unit fails then fail this too.
So, Add `Requires=bluetooth.service` in `myweb.service` and `systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: I tried with Requires= and also tried with Wants=, but still it is not working